# Nan when training model wit RMSE/ RMSLE loss function

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, nan, loss-function

I know there are already a lot of people who asked a similar question, I tried everything mentioned there if it was applicable to my case, but nothing helped. The regression training model ist the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense , Dropout
from keras import backend as K

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 128, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation = "relu", input_dim = 28))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 128, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation = "relu"))
model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = root_mean_squared_logarithmic_error)

model.fit(train_set, labels, batch_size = 32, epochs = 30)
```

and with the loss function defined below this leads to:

```
Epoch 12/30
27423/27423 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.4143     
Epoch 13/30
27423/27423 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.4070     
Epoch 14/30
27423/27423 [==============================] - 1s - loss: nan
```

If I use a standard `mean_squared_error` loss function `loss = nan` is not occurring. If either of the following two  custom `loss functions` is used (naturally those are what I am trying to get running) `loss = nan` is occurring at some point.

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))

def root_mean_squared_logarithmic_error(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_log = K.log(K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), None) + 1.)
    y_true_log = K.log(K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), None) + 1.)
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred_log - y_true_log), axis = -1))
```

Doing 10 fold cross validation with `root_mean_squared_logarithmic_error` loss function the `loss = nan` often occurs in the middle, in some folds only at the last epoch (in sum it occurred in 5 folds). In one fold the loss converged to `15.6132` and remained there for all remaining epochs. 4 folds finished without `loss = nan` occurring.

The input data is corrected for `nans` and outliers. I tried several different rescaling methods, all with no effect to the matter

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
```

I also varied input data (testing with subsets of the data) in which case `loss = nan` occurred in every subset (even every two column combinations). I also varied the `neurons`, the `dropout`, the `optimizer` (to `'adam'`) and the `batch_size`.

Thanks for your ideas, I appreciate every help!

Comment: Hi I'm getting the same problem... Did you happen to solve it? If so, can you kindly post your solution @dennis? Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately not, I am still trying to avoid the nans without any results...

Comment: In case you've found a solution, please post it :) I'm getting the exact same problem and have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 3):

Adding `abs()` to loss function helped me with this problem.

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
        return np.abs(K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code of Evgeniy, change np.abs for K.abs:

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.abs(K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)))
```